Magento 2.4.4: no image showing for configurable product inside product recommendations section
I have installed product recommendation module (Magento marketplace) to my site (Magento 2.4.4). The recommendation products are showing in the frontend inside the prodcut details page. The simple products are working alright. But the configurable products have no image showing and the image Url is 'https://local.magento.com/media/catalog/productno_selection'. I wonder if there is way to update the image Url to the first child's image Url.
